# Matrix constructor and method in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, constructor, instance

So here is a nested list [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

I want to wrap it in a type called Matrix, and make it an instance of the classes Eq, Num, and Show

I have already created (add, sub, mul) operations for nested lists (matrices).  How do I overload (+ - *) operators so that + maps to add, - maps to sub, and * maps to mul?  So I can do this

```
> ma = Matrix [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> mb = Matrix [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
> ma + mb
> ma - mb
> ma * mb
```

Thanks

EDIT

this is my attempt so far

```
> add = zipWith (zipWith (+))
> sub = zipWith (zipWith (-))
> data Matrix a = Matrix [[a]] deriving (Eq, Show)
> instance Num (Matrix a)
>   where
>   (+) x y = Matrix $ add x y
>   (-) x y = Matrix $ sub x y
```

This is what I get from ghci

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[[c0]]' with actual type `Matrix a'
    In the first argument of `sub', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `sub x y'
    In the expression: Matrix $ sub x y
```

EDIT #2
The last thing I need to figure out right now is

how to I print

```
1 2
3 4
```

Instead of Matrix [[1,2],[3,4]]

Comment: @Mikhail Blame my grammar error on too much Haskell Kool-Aid

Comment: Replace `(+) x y` with `(+) (Matrix x) (Matrix y)`. The error message tells you that `sub` expects a `[[a]]`, but you're giving it `Matrix a`.

Comment: Added a `Show` instance that you requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you having a problem with defining a `Num` instance for your type? Try this code:

```
data Matrix a = Matrix [[a]]
              deriving (Eq)

plus_mat :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
plus_mat = zipWith (zipWith (+))

instance Num a => Num (Matrix a)
  where
    (Matrix a) + (Matrix b) = Matrix $ plus_mat a b
    (-)                     = undefined
    (*)                     = undefined
    negate                  = undefined
    abs                     = undefined
    signum                  = undefined
    fromInteger             = undefined
```

Testing:

```
*Main> Matrix [[1,2],[3,4]] + Matrix [[5,6],[7,8]]
Matrix [[6,8],[10,12]]
```

Definitions of the remaining class methods are left as exercise.

And here's a `Show` instance for `Matrix`:

```
import Data.List

instance Show a => Show (Matrix a)
  where
    show (Matrix a) = intercalate "\n" $ map (intercalate " " . map show) a
```

Testing:

```
*Main Data.List> Matrix [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: this is my add function
add = zipWith (zipWith (+))
can I just plug `add` in there somewhere?

Comment: I've updated my example. In your code, replace `plus_mat` with `add`.

Comment: @Qin You have written instance Matrix ... instead of instance Num ... ?

Comment: You probably have a syntax error somewhere. Copy my example to a new file and replace `plus_mat` with your own function, then add definitions for other class methods (`(*)`,`(-)`,...).

Comment: Nvm my last comment.  see my EDIT #2

Comment: -1 for bare code with no explanation (specifically the show instance).

Answer (score 7):

If you inspect the type of your `add` and `sub`, you will see the issue.

```
ghci> :t add
add :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
ghci> :t sub
sub :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Mikhail's suggestion was to essentially unwrap the 2D list and rewrap it in the Num instance methods. Another way to do this is to modify your `add` and `sub` methods to work on Matrices instead. Here I use a "lifting" approach, where I write combinators to "lift" a function from one type to another.

```
-- unwraps the 2d list from a matrix
unMatrix :: Matrix a -> [[a]]
unMatrix (Matrix m) = m

-- lifts a 2d list operation to be a Matrix operation
liftMatrixOp :: ([[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
liftMatrixOp f x y = Matrix $ f (unMatrix x) (unMatrix y)

-- lifts a regular operation to be a 2d list operation
lift2dOp :: (a -> a -> a) -> [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
lift2dOp f = zipWith (zipWith f)
```

With these combinators, defining `add` and `sub` is simply a matter of lifting appropriately.

```
add, sub :: Num a => Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
add = liftMatrixOp add2D
sub = liftMatrixOp sub2D

add2D, sub2D :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
add2D = lift2dOp (+)
sub2D = lift2dOp (-)
```

Now that we have functions that work on Matrices, the Num instance is simple

```
instance (Num a) => Num (Matrix a) where
  (+) = add
  (-) = sub
  ..etc..
```

Of course we could have combined `lift2dOp` and `liftMatrixOp` into one convenience function:

```
-- lifts a regular operation to be a Matrix operation
liftMatrixOp' :: (a -> a -> a) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a -> Matrix a
liftMatrixOp' = liftMatrixOp . lift2dOp

instance (Num a) => Num (Matrix a) where
  (+) = liftMatrixOp' (+)
  (-) = liftMatrixOp' (-)
  (*) = liftMatrixOp' (*)
  ..etc..
```

Now you try: define `liftMatrix :: (a -> a) -> Matrix a -> Matrix a`, a lifting function for unary functions. Now use that to define `negate`, `abs`, and `signum`. The docs suggest that `abs x * signum x` should always be equivalent to `x`. See if this is true for our implementation.

```
ghci> quickCheck (\xs -> let m = Matrix xs in abs m * signum m == m)
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

In fact, if you write `liftMatrix` with the more lenient type signature, it can be used to define a `Functor` instance for Matrices.

```
liftMatrix :: (a -> b) -> Matrix a -> Matrix b

instance Functor (Matrix a) where
  fmap = liftMatrix
```

Now think about how you could implement `fromInteger`. Implementing this allows you to do stuff like this in ghci:

```
ghci> Matrix [[1,2],[3,4]] + 1
Matrix [[2,3],[4,5]]
```

That's how it works the way I implemented it, anyways. Remember that any numeric literal `n` in Haskell code is actually transformed into `fromInteger n`, which is why this works.

I think that's enough fun for now, but if you need more exercises, try getting comfortable with this `Arbitrary` instance of Matrices:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Matrix a) where
  arbitrary = liftM Matrix arbitrary
```